# Floating point number generation in C on Montavista on PPC

Tags: c, powerpc

I have the following simple program to generate floating point random numbers between 1 and 4:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

main()
{
    int i = 0;
    float u;

        srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
        for(i = 0;i< 10000 ; i++)
        {
            u =  ((4-1)*((float)rand()/RAND_MAX))+1;
            printf("The random value for iteration = %d is %2.4f \n", i, u);
        }
}
```

It successfully generates floating point random numbers between 1 and 4 on an x86 Red Hat Linux machine. But the same program produces 0.0000 as random number on a PPC running Montavista Linux.

Could someone explain why and how to make this work on the PPC Montavista ?

Comment: Do you mean that it *always* produces 0.0000?

Comment: To print `0.0000` the value of the expression `((float)rand()/RAND_MAX)` must be `-0.3333333333`. I doubt that very much even though I have no experience with Montavista on PPC

Comment: @pmg - agreed.  I could see if there was some weirdness on gcc on PPC where it improperly did the `rand()/RAND_MAX` division before the `float` cast (mind you, I can't imagine it's actually doing that!), but then that would always give you `1.0000`, not `0.0000`.

Comment: Yes it does. The version of compiler used is : ppc_82xx-gcc (GCC) 3.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

A hunch is that you should be using double instead of float or printing `(double)u`, since `%f` takes a double. I was under the impression that floats were automatically promoted to double when passed to a vararg function though.

You could also try printing `(int)(u*10000)`.

Comment: Indeed, floats are promoted to double when passed to a vararg function.